# Decrypt in Crypto-JS gives numeric hexadecimal output instead of original plaintext string

Tags: javascript, cryptojs

I put together a simple test using the example from the [Crypto-JS source site at Google code](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#AES):

In page header:

```
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/aes.js"></script>
```

In a Javascript function:

```
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("Message", "Secret Passphrase");
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, "Secret Passphrase");

alert('encrypted: '+encrypted+'  decrypted: '+decrypted);
```

but the output is:

```
encrypted: U2FsdGVkX19hsNqFBS5xcUoVBCu/hPHepEwZchqnUVU=
decrypted: 4d657373616765
```

[image: image of decrypted output]

What am I missing?

Comment: Just FYI, the output is the numeric code-point value of each character in the plaintext, expressed as a two-digit hex number. Observe this with `String.fromCharCode.apply(String, "4d657373616765".match(/.{2}/g).map(function(d) { return parseInt(d, 16); }))`.

Comment: The "documentation" for the library could certainly be improved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8) // "Message"
```

See https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#The_Hasher_Output

> The hash you get back isn't a string yet. It's a **WordArray** object. When you use a WordArray object in a string context, it's automatically converted to a **hex** string.
>
> You can convert a WordArray object to **other** **formats** by explicitly calling the **toString** method and passing an **encoder**.